# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: support, deletion, undeletion

I answered my own question and the answer was deleted by a moderator. The answer is an adequate solution to the question asked, but I am looking for other solutions. I feel that my answer could have helped future readers. Why was it deleted?

[How do you generate a surface who's value around the origin is within some range](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637506/)

My answer, (for non moderators) was:

---

Right now I am using: $$\frac{\sin(x+x_0)\sin(y+y_0)+1}{2}$$ where we uniformly choose $x_0, y_0 \in [0,2\pi]$. Generated surfaces look kind of like peaks, saddles (like $xy$), parabolas and planes.

Comment: I just looked at the answer, and it looks more like a comment or something that should be incorporated into the question. I can restore it as a comment to your question or to an answer, or I can append it to your question.